# Start prometheus within spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, micrometer

I'm new to micrometer and Prometheus, I only used dropwizards metrics. It bothers me a bit, that I actually need to have 3 different instances up and running to see the metrics

- The spring boot application itself with micrometer
- Prometheus for metrics aggregation
- And grafana for visualisation.

With dropwizard I could expose aggregated metrics right away.

That is, why I was curious about whether it would be possible to start Prometheus together with my spring boot application to expose nicely aggregated data right away. So far I couldn't find anything useful so I hope someone here might be able to help me.

Comment: Do you only have one Spring Boot Application? And what kind of metrics are you interested in?

Comment: Yes, one application. I need the time aggregated values of a simple counter, like "number of failed requests in the last 5 minutes".

Comment: what do you mean by Prometheus together with my spring boot application ?  both as single application ?

Comment: Yes both as one application in the best case. If that is not possible maybe it would be possible to configure the spring project in a way that at startup it also starts a prometheus instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Microservices. Prometheus is written in Go, so Java won't be able to start it, though you could use something like [TestContainers](https://bsideup.github.io/posts/local_development_with_testcontainers/) (a Java library for starting Docker containers) to start up a Prometheus instance for you.

If you don't want Prometheus itself, you could startup a `SimpleMeterRegistry`, or a `LoggingMeterRegistry` that do some lightweight aggregations within your app (you may need to extend them to get exactly what you are looking for).

There is even a DropWizard based registry, but I haven't played with that one.